# How do I make an Input required in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two Inputs, that have to be required, in order to use the "Add"-Button or I was thinking to use *ngIf to make the button visible or not, but it doesnt work. Whats wrong?

```
<input
    #neueEintragBeschreibung
    placeholder="Eintrag hinzufügen"
    class="lg-text-input"
  />

  <input
    #neuesEintragFaelligkeitsdatum
    placeholder="Faelligkeitsdatum hinzufügen"
    class="lg-text-input"
  />

  <div *ngIf="neueEintragBeschreibung.value">
  <button class="btn-primary" (click)="addEintrag(neueEintragBeschreibung.value, neuesEintragFaelligkeitsdatum.value)">
    Add</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Use [Angular Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview) and mark the field as required using a validator rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to access `input.value` this way. You should use the forms API to do so. E.g:

```html
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="handleSubmit(form)">
  <input type="text" required name="myField" ngModel />

  <ng-container *ngIf="form.valid">
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

```js
handleSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  console.log(`You entered: ${form.value.myField}`);
}
```

What's happening here:

1. You create a form with one field, called "myField".
2. You make "myField" required by using the `required` attribute.
3. You render the "Add" button only when the form is valid. Since the form has a required field, it will only be valid once this field is filled by the user.

Remember to add `FormsModule` to your module's imports.

Comment: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b2bupn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer at the following link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-reactive-forms-introduction

**stackblitz**:*https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-im2nap?*file=src/app/app.module.ts

You have to use Angular Forms and mark the field as required using a validator rule:

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm)">
  <div>
    <label>
      Name:
      <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Your name">
    </label>
    <div *ngIf="myForm.get('name').invalid && (myForm.get('name').dirty || myForm.get('name').touched)">
      Please provide a name.
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">Send</button>
</form>
```

in Your component, you have to import:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
```

And:

```
myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['Sammy', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  onSubmit(form: FormGroup) {
    console.log('Valid?', form.valid); // true or false
    console.log('Name', form.value.name);
  }
```